# labels in leaflet r with HTML tags

Tags: html, r, leaflet, r-leaflet

All good souls, help needed. I am creating a leaflet map and cannot resolve a strange issue with labels. I created labels with few variables and the labels render ok if the first variable is numeric, but they fail if the first is a string - any idea what's the issue?
Let's start with a dummy spdf:

```
library(htmltools)
library(sp)
library(leaflet)

df <- new("SpatialPointsDataFrame", data = structure(list(PMID = c(184397, 184397), SPACEID = c("184397_1", "184397_2")), .Names = c("PMID", "SPACEID"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), coords.nrs = numeric(0), coords = structure(c(-0.14463936, -0.14468822, 51.50726534, 51.50730171), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2"), c("x", "y"))), bbox = structure(c(-0.14468822, 51.50726534, -0.14463936, 51.50730171), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("x", "y"), c("min", "max"))), proj4string = new("CRS", projargs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
```

now we (m)apply a simple HTML line (the original used the df rows but it is not needed and can be simplified to

```
df@data$HT<-mapply(function(x,y){htmltools::HTML(sprintf("<h2>%s</h2> %s",x,y))},1,"L", SIMPLIFY = F)
```

and this one will work fine. But if the order is reversed - instead of (1,"L") we change to ("L",1) - it fails:

```
df@data$HT<-mapply(function(x,y){htmltools::HTML(sprintf("<h2>%s</h2> %s",x,y))},"L",1, SIMPLIFY = F)
```

in the first case the map contains correct labels and in the other one it produces empty label

```
leaflet() %>%
addTiles() %>%
addMarkers(data = df, label = ~ HT)
```

if I use `label = ~as.character(HT)` it shall produce a verbatim HTML tag, but not the label. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After playing around the code, I found that replacing `mapply()` with `map2()` in the purrr package does the trick here. I am not totally sure why this is the case. Both Slav and I confirmed that this solution is working on our machines.

```
library(sp)
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)
library(purrr)

df@data$HT1 <- map2(1, "L", ~htmltools::HTML(sprintf("<h2>%s</h2> %s",.x,.y))) 
df@data$HT2 <- map2("L", 1, ~htmltools::HTML(sprintf("<h2>%s</h2> %s",.x,.y))) 

leaflet()%>%
addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>%
addLabelOnlyMarkers(data = df, label = ~HT2, 
                    labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = TRUE, direction = 'center',
                                                textOnly = FALSE, textsize = "15px"))
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: the only challenge remaining is how to use html escape on it, but it is another query to deal with it. The answer perfectly resolves my issue

Comment: word of warning when someone would like to copy it to resolve their challenge - map2 is specifically for 2 arguments only, it does not work with any other number of args

Comment: you need to use pmap with slightly different syntax (arguments as a list and you refer to them as ..1,..2,..3), so pmap(list("L",1,"W"),~htmltools::HTML(sprintf("<h2>%s</h2> %s %s",..1,..2,..3)))

Comment: @Slav That is a great note for future readers. Thanks for that.